# Cardinality of the closure of subset of a dense subset

Tags: gn.general-topology, cardinal-characteristics

Is the following true? Given a first countable Hausdorff space $X$ and a dense subset $Y\subset X$ which is initially $2^\omega$-initially Lindelöf in $X$. Let $F$ be a subset  of $Y$ such that $\vert F\vert\leq 2^{\omega }$. Then $\big\vert \overline{F} \big\vert \leq 2^\omega  $.

I actually want to prove something stronger, namely that $Y$ is Lindelöf in $X$. The proof goes by transfinite induction on $\alpha<\aleph_1$, one of the steps require the above statement to be true, so maybe some of the hypothesis above are not needed for that particular statement.

By Lindelöf in $X$, I mean that for any open cover $\gamma$ of $X$ there exists a countable subfamily $\eta\subset\gamma $ that covers $Y$. By $2^\omega$-initially Lindelöf I mean that for every open cover $\gamma$ of $X$ with  $\vert \gamma \vert\leq 2^\omega$ there exists a countable subfamily $\eta\subset \gamma $ that covers $Y$.

**This question has been cross-posted and answered in MathStackExchange**
Here is the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3679758/on-the-cardinality-of-the-closure-of-a-subset-of-a-dense-subset/3679820#3679820).

Comment: $Y$ is Lindelöf in $X$ is just the same as $Y$ is Lindelöf as a subspace of $X$ (in its own right).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma No, you can find a counter example [in this paper](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/016686419390080W?token=C7A9A4A1CEB207FCC7B6F2B899B5D83062356C8FC6EB528931E76C7C02C1ADC30CA62BC621DB16633631660E21ECB476)